# How to notify when user is pressing "Cmd + c" or "ctrl + c" on selected text in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there any way to detect the combo key press and notify user using Angular JS. For example I want to notify user when they press "ctrl+c" or "cmd+c" on selected text that they are copied to clipboard.

So far I have tried using https://github.com/mgonto/mgo-mousetrap. But problem is that it invokes the function but doesn't copy selected text to clipboard.

Help would be really really appreciated.

Following is sample code http://jsfiddle.net/meetgodhani/7ypfcjgm/3/.

HTML

```
<span ng-click="superCoolAction()" w-mousetrap="{'command+c': superCoolAction}">http://www.sample.com</span>
```

SCRIPT

```
angular.module('superapp', ['mgo-mousetrap']);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.superCoolAction = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Super cool");
}
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: @bmceldowney I have updated my question with jsfiddle.

Comment: Have you tried ng-copy, its available in angularjs

Comment: @Siraj ng-copy I think is good only for input field.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `event.preventDefault();` line from your handler.